# Removed comma from last while working with StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder, stringbuffer

I've the following Java program and I don't want "," to be assign after my last element, what to do ?

```
String range = "400-450";
        Integer startRange = null;
        Integer endRange = null;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(range,"-");  
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) { 
            startRange = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
            endRange= Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
        } 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = startRange; i <= endRange; i++) {
            sb.append(i).append(",");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
```

The output should be 
`400,401,402,403,404,405,406,407,408,409,410,411,412,413,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,421,422,423,424,425,426,427,428,429,430,431,432,433,434,435,436,437,438,439,440,441,442,443,444,445,446,447,448,449,450`  --> without comma at last

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple as

```
for (int i = startRange; i <= endRange; i++) {
   sb.append(i);
   if(i != endRange)
        sb.append(",");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For **Java 8** you could switch to new class [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) which has beed added for *exactly that purpose*:

```
    StringJoiner sb = new StringJoiner(",");
    for (int i = startRange; i <= endRange; i++) {
        sb.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Doing it manually, I'd suggest adding the comma *before the item* and then use substring(1):

```
    for (int i = startRange; i <= endRange; i++) {
        sb.append(",").append(i);
    }
    //Check for empty before!
    System.out.println(sb.substring(1));
```

Comment: This doesn't compile as `StringJoiner.add()` takes a `CharSequence` not an integer.  You need `sb.add(String.valueOf(i));`

Answer (score 1):

As @Jan says, use `StringJoiner` if you have Java8.  Otherwise you could add a separator before the new entry and treat the first item differently by initialising the separator to blank.

```
   String separator = "";
    for (int i = startRange; i <= endRange; i++) {
        sb.append(separator).append(i);
        separator = ",";
    }
```

This is the Java8 version

```
    StringJoiner sb = new StringJoiner(",");
    for (int i = startRange; i <= endRange; i++) {
        sb.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just let the last loop appending the commas stop before the last element is reached:

```
String range = "400-450";
        Integer startRange = null;
        Integer endRange = null;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(range,"-");  
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()) { 
            startRange = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
            endRange= Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); 
        } 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        // here, the "<=" was changed to "<"
        for (int i = startRange; i < endRange; i++) {
            sb.append(i).append(",");
        }
        // append last element
        sb.append(endrange)
        System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: Still comma (,) coming at last, I dont want that

Comment: Thank you for the hint! See the second-to-last line for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

You are appending `","` after each `i`
try to append `","` only if you didn't reach the endRange

do:

```
for (int i = startRange; i <= endRange; i++) {
            sb.append(i)
            if (i != endRange)
              sb.append(",");
        }
```

this way `","` will not be added to sb after last number.

Comment: Please don't just post code - add an explanation of why this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Joiner (guava) for Java < 8.

```
List<Integer> numbers = Lists.newArrayList(1, 3, 4, 5, 23);
System.out.println(Joiner.on(",").join(numbers));
```

And the output is:

1,3,4,5,23